# TypeError: NoneType object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. Everything works except that instead of printing out my print statement I get this error instead, ""and your favorite color is %s")(name, quest, color)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" Here's my code below.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
quest = input("What is your quest?")
color = input("What is your favorite color?")

print ("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s,"
"and your favorite color is %s")(name, quest, color)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your string format syntax is wrong

```
print("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s and your favorite color is %s" % (name, quest, color))
```

Though you may prefer the newer `.format` style

```
print("Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is {} and your favorite color is {}".format(name, quest, color))
```

Or, as of Python3.6 you can use f-strings (note the `f` before the first `"` below)

```
print(f"Ah, so your name is {name}, your quest is {quest} and your favorite color is {color}")
```

---

The error you are receiving is due to the evaluation of `print`.  Given the error I'm assuming you're using python3 which is doing something like this

```
print('hello')()
```

This is evaluated as

```
(print('hello'))()
```

which will call print with the argument `'hello'` first.  The `print` function returns `None` so what happens next is

```
(None)()
```

or equivalently

```
None()
```

`None` is not callable, leading to your error

Comment: One of the best explanations I have seen yet +1